# python: csv to json conversion when csv contains unicode

Tags: python, json, csv, unicode, stringio

I'm trying to use the following code (within web2py) to read a csv file and convert it into a json object:

```
import csv
import json

originalfilename, file_stream = db.tablename.file.retrieve(info.file) 
file_contents =   file_stream.read()

csv_reader = csv.DictReader(StringIO(file_contents))
json = json.dumps([x for x in csv_reader])
```

This produces the following error:

> 'utf8' codec can't decode byte
>   0xa0 in position 1: invalid start byte

Apparently, there is a problem handling the spaces in the .csv file. The problem appears to stem from the json.dumps() line. The traceback from that point on:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../web2py/gluon/restricted.py", line 212, in restricted
    exec ccode in environment
  File ".../controllers/default.py", line 2345, in <module>
  File ".../web2py/gluon/globals.py", line 194, in <lambda>
    self._caller = lambda f: f()
  File ".../web2py/gluon/tools.py", line 3021, in f
    return action(*a, **b)
  File ".../controllers/default.py", line 697, in generate_vis
    request.vars.json = json.dumps(list(csv_reader))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 243, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

Any suggestions regarding how to resolve this, or another way to get a csv file (which contains a header; using StringIO) into a json object that won't produce similar complications? Thank you.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3? Please do include the *full* traceback.

Comment: You don't need to use a list comprehension where a simple `list()` call would do: `json.dumps(list(csv_reader))` would be more efficient.

Comment: Last but not least, you'll need to share how you read the file with us. What web framework is this?

Comment: Please clarify the exactly line with a error.

Comment: python pandas offers very convenient way or handling csv files: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html, if that's of any help

Comment: It's the web2py framework with python 2.7. Edits made to the original to indicate how the file is being read.

Comment: Simon - I'm trying to avoid using pandas as long as it's possible.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters and sergzach - added the traceback.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - full traceback added, with dir names redacted.

Comment: JSON needs unicode text output. This means that all your *string* input needs to be decodable to Unicode. You have byte data that is not decodable. Decode manually first. What encoding does your data use?

Comment: The function in question deals with user-uploaded files (in csv or tab-delimited format), so it's not known in advance what sort of encoding will come up.

Answer (score 3):

The `csv` module (under Python 2) is purely byte-based; all strings you get out of it are bytes. However JSON is Unicode character-based, so there is an implicit conversion when you try to write out the bytes you got from CSV into JSON. Python guessed UTF-8 for this, but your CSV file wasn't UTF-8 - it was probably Windows code page 1252 (Western European - like ISO-8859-1 only not quite).

A quick fix would be to transcode your input (`file_contents= file_contents.decode('windows-1252').encode('utf-8')`), but probably you don't really want to rely on `json` guessing a particular encoding.

Best would be to explicitly decode your strings at the point of reading them from CSV. Then JSON will be able to cope with them OK. Unfortately `csv` doesn't have built-in decoding (at least in this Python version), but you can do it manually:

```
class UnicodeDictReader(csv.DictReader):
    def __init__(self, f, encoding, *args, **kwargs):
        csv.DictReader.__init__(self, f, *args, **kwargs)
        self.encoding = encoding
    def next(self):
        return {
            k.decode(self.encoding): v.decode(self.encoding)
            for (k, v) in csv.DictReader.next(self).items()
        }

csv_reader = UnicodeDictReader(StringIO(file_contents), 'windows-1252')
json_output = json.dumps(list(csv_reader))
```

> it's not known in advance what sort of encoding will come up

Well that's more of a problem, since it's impossible to guess accurately what encoding a file is in. You would either have to specific a particular encoding, or give the user a way to signal what the encoding is, if you want to support non-ASCII characters properly.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing your final line with

```
json = json.dumps([x.encode('utf-8') for x in csv_reader])
```

Comment: The specific character that's causing the issue in this particular case is '\xa0'; encode('utf-8') produces an error when encountering it.

Answer (score 1):

Running unidecode over the file contents seems to do the trick:

```
from isounidecode import unidecode

...

file_contents =   unidecode(file_stream.read())

...
```

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: That's replacing all non-ASCII characters with mangled best-fit ASCII versions - are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: You make a good point. It may not be a universal solution, but works for my purposes, and seems to better than some other options at dealing with a multitude of cases in such a way that no error is produced (as opposed to encode(), which gets tripped up by '\xa0', for example).